# Ball collision logic with layers of rectangles

Tags: java, swing

I'm writing a game that simulates COVID. There is a main boundary - everything is contained inside this. There are also user-defined dynamically created inner boundaries called "Quarantine Zones". If a person (ball) is inside this quarantine zone, it shouldn't be able to escape. And other people shouldn't be able to enter the area until the zone is removed. The people move between "Home" and "Office" and I'm struggling to write collision logic.

[game screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeJOi.png)

**What is the best way of making sure a person can get to their destination if they collide with a quarantine zone on the way?**

Here's some logic I've been playing around with but little success

```
  class Person {
    ....

    public void move(ArrayList<Boundary> boundaries){

        for (Boundary boundary : boundaries){
            if (boundary == Simulation.MAIN_BOUNDARY) continue;

            if (boundary.contains(this)){
                System.out.println("im inside the box");
                // move somehow
                return;
            }
            else if (boundary.onBoundary(this)){
                System.out.println("im outside the box");
                // move somehow
                return;
            }
        }

        // move to home / office
        goTo(officeCoords);
  }
```

Comment: Well, a simple way to move those people would be to have them "bounce" from the border, i.e. calculate the side of the box the person is colliding with, get the normal vector (e.g. 1/0 for the left wall or -1/0 for the bottom wall if y goes down) and mirror the person's inverted movement vector around that normal (look for billard game tutorials to get some deeper explanations). Or just let people turn in random angles until they don't run into the wall anymore.

Comment: @Thomas ok thanks, ill give this ago. How do you remember direction of travel after each bounce?

Comment: Well, a person should know the direction they're travelling in, shouldn't they? So that's where the changed direction should go. Btw, you might need to actually calculate 2 positions for collision detection: the current one and the target direction. Otherwise a fast moving person might just "jump" in and out of the box, i.e. they might be inside next to the wall but in the next frame they're outside due to their speed.

Comment: *"If a person (ball) is inside this quarantine zone, it shouldn't be able to escape. And other people shouldn't be able to enter the area.."* So you're .. modeling a perfect world in which those constraints actually work? Huh..

Comment: If you want something more advanced than random movement, there's a breadth-first search, depth-first search, and A* search. Oh, and your game board has way too many zonea.  It's visually confusing for the user.